# Is there a straight-forward way of doing an ORM roundtrip workflow in Grails 3+?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

For the last few years I have been a Symfony developer and one of the things I enjoy the most is the fact that I don't have to write/maintain entities by hand.

Through Doctrine (the integrated ORM) I can extract the table metadata and relations through

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import SomeBundle yaml
```

And then I can generate the ORM entity classes

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:entities SomeBundle
```

And I'm friggin' done.

Need to migrate?, no problem. Use this command to create a migration:

```
doctrine:migrations:diff
```

And the following to migrate to it:

```
doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

For Grails, it seems that there is no straight forward way, unless I go and download the Hibernate tools and a tool like Liquibase.

There seem to be a couple of plugins that did this, but the one for reverse engineering from a database does not seem supported for Grails 3 (db-reverse-engineer) and the one for migrations I tried, but does not seem stable enough (database-migration).

Am I just looking in the wrong place?, if not, how do you as a professional Grails developer solve these needs?

Answer (score 1):

**No there is not a straight forward way to make a "round-trip" as you describe in Grails 3.x.**

Most plugins aren't going to be 3.x ready yet. 3.x is still quite new.

That said, the reverse engineering plugin isn't designed to be a fully automated one-shot handles everything type of plugin. It's suppose to be a running start that you take the last bit by hand.

The migration plugin on the other hand is fully production ready and very stable in 2.x.

Comment: I understand the difference between schema and domain, and nope, I am not letting schema dictate my domain. In my opinion, reverse engineering helps guarantee consistency with the model/domain, it is not dictating anything and allows to eliminate boring manual steps, and in the end the application produces the actual schema when deploying the application. Migrations allow for data model versioning. Sorry, I don't think this is an answer to my questions.

Comment: Updated to reflect just answering your question as apposed to explaining why Grails doesn't behave in such a manner. I don't understand what "boring or manual" steps you are talking about since the migration plugin handles (or GORM by itself without the migration plugin in most cases) keeping your schema in sync with your model/domain. The migration plugin is fantastic and automates everything if you choose to manually verify things instead.

Comment: So, would this means this needs to get done through external tools like Hibernate Tools and Liquibase?, if so, what would be the correct way to integrate those methods?, since they seem to be java based and not groovy (I'm a total newb at groovy and grails)

Comment: The database migration plugin is a Grails wrapper for Liquibase. I can't speak of the Hibernate Tools. The correct way, if you needed, would be to integrate them into your Gradle build if you needed to do so (using Grails 3.x)

Comment: What about the generated Java classes?, where should those be put?

Comment: Any java related source for your Grails project should be under `src/java`.